# Check if we are saving the same row again in table? Validation in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activerecord

I have a user model and a post model. I want users to vote for the post.
so I created a vote model. the three look like this.

User Model:-

```
  has_many :posts
  has_many :votes
```

Post Model:-

```
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :votes
```

Vote Model:-

```
  belongs_to :post
  belongs_to :user
```

What will be the validation code to check whether the row exists or not?

Also there is a functionality for a user to vote maximum 3 votes in a day. Any help on how to do that, i.e reset the votes column etc.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: you can put a uniqueness with scope validation to check that the record is duplicate or not]

Comment: i think you should think about the row in more specific terms (and maybe clarify your question).  When you are checking for a row's existence, i assume you mean a vote row, correct?  And what if it does exist?  You really want to check for #votes to be less than or equal to 3 for a given user and post.  is that correct?

Comment: How does the votes belongs_to :votes work out... are you voting on votes also?

Comment: Hey sorry i have edited the question for vote model

Comment: To mr rogers...see there is a blog and i am reading a post of another user, now i will click a button vote which will make an ajax request and create a vote active record object and saved with that post_id and the user_id. Now if i click that button it should show me an error that i have already voted for that post from the server. First i make out this by removing the button through javascript but still you can send a post request through console so,

Comment: I think may be this will work. Tell me if i am doing wrong or a better solution:-

Comment: before_save :validate_vote?     def validate_vote?
  user   =  self.user
  request  =  self.request
  if Vote.find_by_user_id(user.id) and Vote.find_by_request_id(request.id)
   return false
  else
   return true
  end
 end

Answer (score 0):

Check for the presence of the value with the uniqueness, e.g.;

For checking the presence of the row value;

```
  validates :row_name, presence: true
```

For checking the uniqueness of the row value;

```
  validates :row_name, uniqueness: true
```

Comment: For posting minimum three votes per day you need to fetch the no of votes and its count before the user posts any vote and the count should be less than 3 for a particular day(Use filter for it before_save). Use eager loading for fetching the associated records.

Comment: That will be done. But what the next day, user should have another three votes everyday.

Comment: Just get a count of the user's votes for the current day (as opposed to their total vote count) to see whether it's under the daily maximum. No need for cron jobs etc. for that.

Comment: That is what I have told you need check the no. votes on daily basis and for the current day the user should not allowed to cross the vote count to 3.